# Stop Laravel installer installing latest version automatically

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I have been using `laravel installer` to install `laravel 5.2`, now suddenly it is automatically installing version `5.3`.

Is there way to **configure** laravel installer to install **only** version 5.2.

I installed it globally and found this line

```
$app = new Symfony\Component\Console\Application('Laravel Installer', '1.3.3');
```

in `/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel`, but stacked here to configure it

Comment: Thanks @Hari Harker to edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `5.2` option to your command.

```
laravel new project --5.2
```

This option is added at `installer` version 1.3.4

https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/master/src/NewCommand.php#L29

Comment: not working.
 [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  The "--5.2" option does not exist.

Comment: Please make sure you have the latest version of the installer. Version 1.3.4

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if it worked.

Comment: vote up my question also if you find it meaningful question please

Answer (score 2):

If you try it with composer this is the code:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.2.*"
```

I found it in laravel 5.2 documentation [Laravel 5.2 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation)

Comment: isn't way to configure laravel installer, i installed it globally and found this line,
$app = new Symfony\Component\Console\Application('Laravel Installer', '1.3.3');
but i stucked here